# Load data from external server to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I am connection to Oracle using PHP.
Now i've a file in PHP containing some data which I want to load into Oracle database table. Easiest way to do this is to read file and create insert queries to do this.

But can I load this data from my file in my server into a oracle table without uploading the file to oracle server as i don't have its FTP access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another consideration for bulk loading data into Oracle table(s) is the SQL Loader utility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upload it the ORACLE server in order to do your inserts.

I have a similar example:
  I read  .csv files  which have a lot of records  regarding used cars' makes, models
and quotes .
   I have a class which  reads these files ( from my local PC) prepairs insert, updates and deletes makes all these CRUD operations in a REMOTE ORACLE SERVER.
 Your web server should have access, authorization, to connect to the ORACLE instance, that's all.